# Как сравнить 2 масиива на значения?

Tags: php, массивы

Предположим, что есть массивы

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$b = array(3,2,1);
```

Как мне определить - одинаковые ли значения в этих массивах без перебора одного из них 
Мне нужно решение вида

```
if($a == $b){

}
```

Если такое есть конечно. А такой  метод никак не могу присобачить к существующей функции

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {

if (in_array($value, $b)) {

}

}
```

Мне нужно получить на выходе не отличия массивов, а равенства их или не равенства значений массивов.

Comment: Не дубликат ли? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/257960

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сравнить массивы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/257960/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b)

Comment: Не дубликат, так как у меня задача другая.

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene, вы бы вынесли ответ из вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Быстрая реализация (лучше вашего решения):

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = array(3, 2, 1);

function isEqually(&$a, &$b) {
    $i = sizeOf($a);
    $sizeB = sizeOf($b);
    if ($i !== $sizeB) {
        return false;
    }
    while ($i--) {
        if ($a[$i] !== $b[$i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if (isEqually($a, $b)) {
    echo 'Равны';
} else {
    echo 'Не равны';
}
```

Comment: Работает быстрей на 0.00001 и да. Пригодится. спасибо.

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene это с 3мя цифрами, а с большими массивами данных? мой выиграет потому что я не вызываю его 2 раза, и не возвращаю массив который буду потом сравнивать с другим массивом и т.д. И он не делает полный перебор массива, если будет сразу найден не соответствующий элемент.

Comment: @ShevtsovEugene Мне показалось, что ваш вопрос подразумевал "равенство" когда одни элементы первого массива есть во втором (разумеется в тех же количествах), но порядок не важен. Т.е. 123 равно 321. Данный ответ подразумевает полную идентичность. Что же вас на самом деле интересовало ?

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Кстати, если массивы большие, то очень полезно объявлять функцию как `isEqually(&$a, &$b)` тогда массивы не будут копироваться при передаче, что так же ускорит работу

Comment: @Mike да, правильно, я где то в каком то другом посте когда-то писал в комментах, что лучше ссылками передавать, видимо не здесь)) Поправил пост

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно не учитывать порядок элементов, а только их состав, то можно так:

```
function array_values_equal($a, $b) {
    sort($a);
    sort($b);
    return $a === $b;
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3);
$b = array(3, 2, 1);

if (array_values_equal($a, $b))
{
    echo 'Равны';
}
else
{
    echo 'Не равны';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять нативную функцию и сравнить расхождение массивов :

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");

$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
```

результат :

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```